# How to clean up these types of duplicated else blocks?

Tags: c#

I find myself frequently working on codebases that contain logic like this:

```
var _deliveryType = new Dictionary<String, String>();
if (_deliveryType.ContainsKey(fileName)) {
      if (contactPreference == SAMPLE_ENUM) {
         //Perform Action 1
      } else {
         //Perform Action 2
      }

} else {
    //Perform Action 2
}
```

The gist of the issue is that if there's nothing matching that key/value pair, it falls into the outer else block, but if the key does exist and it doesn't have a certain value associated with it, the exact same action as the outer else is performed.

What's the best way to simplify this logic so that I'm not calling the same method twice? This is really stupid but I just can't think of a good way to clean this up.

Comment: if your method call is like return Foo(), then u dont need else

Comment: It's not a return. In this case, it's performing actions on a `List<int>` and then doing some calculations.

Comment: You are not checking an empty dictionary, it's just an example right?

Comment: Correct, just an example. There's data in there.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple answer to this could be to just merge the two `if` statements into one.

```
var _deliveryType = new Dictionary<String, String>();
if (_deliveryType.ContainsKey(fileName) && contactPreference == SAMPLE_ENUM) {
    //Perform Action 1    
} else {
    //Perform Action 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your method call is like return Foo(), then u dont need else. But this is only if you are returning

```
var _deliveryType = new Dictionary<String, String>();
if (_deliveryType.ContainsKey(fileName)) {
      if (contactPreference == SAMPLE_ENUM) {
         return action1()
      }
         return action2();

} 
  return action2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var _deliveryType = new Dictionary<String, String>();
if (!_deliveryType.ContainsKey(fileName) && contactPreference != SAMPLE_ENUM ) {        
  //Perform Action 2        
}else {
  //Perform Action 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the real problem is repeated code: remember to stay DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Refactor.

A first cut might be to extract the repeated code into stand-alone methods:

```
void DoAction1( Dictionary<string,string> dict )
{
  // perform action 1
}
void DoAction2( Dictionary<string,string dict )
{
  // perform action 2
}

Dictionary<string,string> _deliveryType = GetDeliveryType() ;
if (_deliveryType.ContainsKey(fileName))
{
  if (contactPreference == SAMPLE_ENUM)
  {
    DoAction1(_deliveryType) ; 
  }
  else
  {
    DoAction2(_deliveryType) ;
  }
}
else
{
  DoAction2(_deliveryType) ;
}
```

That's helpful, but you still have to expend cycles in the wetware contemplating the 3-way branch. A further refactoring might be, as noted, to then refactor the if-then-else logic itself:

```
Dictionary<string,string> _deliveryType = GetDeliveryType() ;
bool isAction1 = _deliveryType.ContainsKey(fileName) && contactPreference == SAMPLE_ENUM ;
if ( isAction1 )
{
  DoAction1(_deliveryType) ; 
}
else
{
  DoAction2(_deliveryType) ;
}
```

You could use a delegate and simplify things further:

```
Dictionary<string,string> _deliveryType = GetDeliveryType() ;
Action<Dictionary<string,string>> action = _deliveryType.ContainsKey(fileName) && contactPreference == SAMPLE_ENUM ? DoAction1 : DoAction2 ;

action(_deliveryType) ;
```

Now your down to pretty much a straight-line flow of control.